# Implementing Buffer for Byte Arrays in Java

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, arrays, buffer

I am trying to implement a buffer in an android application so I can buffer an incoming stream of byte arrays from a bluetooth connection. I need to do some processing of the byte arrays as i receive them, and that is why I would like to use some sort of buffering.

Basically, I would receive a byte array, store it in the buffer, and then while the next byte arrays are coming into the buffer, I would be pulling them out in the order that they came in to do my processing. In other words, I would need a `first in, first out` implementation.

Could anyone point me in the right direction as to what type of buffer I should use? I am not sure if there is a specific name for what I am looking for. If you could direct me to some good resources for buffer implementation, that would also be very useful.

If any of this isn't clear, please ask and I will do my best to clarify.

Comment: Don't you mean first in first out? "I would be pulling them out in the order that they came in to do my processing".

Comment: Yes, sorry. First in first out is what i mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you buffering the bytes coming in, or arrays of bytes? If you are buffering arrays of bytes, you might want a [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html)

Comment: the data I have coming in is in 16 bit format. So i'm not sure if I should simply use a byte array as a buffer by making it reasonably large. Would that make sense? Or should I make the byte arrays 2 bytes each and then individually buffer those?

Answer (score 1):

ByteBuffer would probably get you started.
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html

Answer (score 1):

For FILO you actually need Stack. Take a look on `java.util.Stack`. You should instantiate it as `new Stack<byte[]>()`. Then you can push data into it and pop it when you have time to process.

Comment: the data I have coming in is in 16 bit format. So i'm not sure if I should simply use a byte array as a buffer by making it reasonably large. Would that make sense? Or should I make the byte arrays 2 bytes each and then individually buffer those?

Answer (score 1):

use StringBuilder , append incoming data in it, you can do following operation in it

1) insert or append string data(or byte convert them to string).

2) append at any specific location.

3) can revers the whole data.

4) can get byte/char from specific location.

let me know if any question.
you can also use Byte Array, ByteBuffer etc

Comment: the data I have coming in is in 16 bit format. So i'm not sure if I should simply use a byte array as a buffer by making it reasonably large. Would that make sense? Or should I make the byte arrays 2 bytes each and then individually buffer those?